# Setup react-styleguidist, Create React App, Typescript, Material UI and styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components, react-styleguidist

Im trying to setup react-styleguidist (RSG) from Create React App 3 (CRA), Typescript, Material UI and styled-components. I'm stuck on this error:

```
./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/ReactExample/ReactExample.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'rsg-components/Wrapper' in '/Users/ofj/code/new-core-web/node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/ReactExample'
```

I followed the docs setting up a wrappers for MUI theme and styled-components:
https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/thirdparties.html#styled-components

**/styleguidist/MuiThemeWrapper.tsx**

```js
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({});
const MuiThemeWrapper = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);

export default MuiThemeWrapper;
```

My styleguidist config:

**/styleguidist.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    components: "src/components/**/layout.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
    propsParser: require('react-docgen-typescript').withCustomConfig(
        './tsconfig.json'
      ).parse,
    serverPort: 6161,
    styleguideComponents: {
      Wrapper: path.join(__dirname, 'styleguidist/MuiThemeWrapper.jsx')
    }
};
```

My tsconfig follows standard CRA / MUI recommendations
https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "pretty": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "types": [
    "./node_modules/@types/"
  ]
}
```

I don't have custom webpack/babel configuration setup cause I don't know how and not messing up the TS transpilation. Maybe this is what's missing in order for RSG to work...?
Or is the error with  rsg-components/ReactExample/ReactExample.js a bug?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: Jamesla, yes I did, but dont remember how, I'm afraid. Also the pairing of RSG with CRA seems like a bad idea because it's sooooo slow...

Comment: I suspect that you were hitting the wall due to needing an alias definition for `rsg-components` needing a redirect to the new correct locations; please see my answer below. Additionally, `styleguideComponents.Wrapper` doesn't seem to work, but I dunno why...

Answer (score 2):

I got it working and hopefully other people might find this useful too, as there are few and only non-typescript example configs to be found so far.

Things to note for my setup:

- react mui app is in `src/`, components are in `src/components/`, using a `modules:` webpack configuration to look into `src/` for absolute imports.
- app has been created using the react app creator.
- `tsconfig.json` autocreated (overriding `noEmit` later specifically for the "ts-loader" only, see below); there's one important exception/addition shown below.
- **no** separate webpack and babel configurations, included in `styleguide.config.js`.

`tsconfig.json` is boilerplate, except for this gem `paths:'rsg-components/*'` here, which needs to be added manually -- it is hidden in the [React Styleguidist's Cookbook](https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/cookbook/#how-to-re-use-the-types-in-styleguidist). Without it, we need to resort to alias definitions in the webpack configuration, including for replacing wrapper! With the correct `paths` definition in `tsconfig.json` things finally start to correctly fall into place.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "rsg-components/*": [
        "node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`styleguide.config.js` lives in the project's top-level directory:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    components: [
        'src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx}',
        'src/models/**/*.ts',
    ],
    ignore: [
        'src/**/index.{ts,tsx}',
    ],
    // We need to override how to decide on what an example file is, in order
    // to remove default which tries to document undocumented components. Ugh.
    // So, only document components for which we also have an explicit
    // documentation file named the same as the component file, but ending in
    // ".md" instead.
    getExampleFilename: (cpath) => {
        return cpath.replace(/\.(tsx?)$/, '.md')
    },
    // Show import commands without the component filename extension and only
    // for the module; also remove the first "src/" path component.
    getComponentPathLine: (cpath) => {
        const cname = ['.tsx', '.ts'].reduce((name, ext) => path.basename(name, ext), cpath)
        const cdir = path.dirname(cpath).replace(/^src\//, '')
        return `import { ${cname} } from ${cdir}`
    },
    // How uncivilized: do not list components lacking an example.
    skipComponentsWithoutExample: true,
    // Always expand the props and methods of components.
    usageMode: 'expand',
    // Support rendering prop types of typescript components.
    propsParser: require('react-docgen-typescript').withCustomConfig(
        './tsconfig.json',
        {
            "compilerOptions": { "noEmit": false },
        }
    ).parse,
    // Replace the standard wrapper for example component usage code with our
    // own wrapper which brings in the Material UI theme.
    styleguideComponents: {
        Wrapper: path.join(__dirname, 'styleguidist/MuiThemeWrapper.tsx')
    },
    // Tell webpack what to look for and where and how to load it.
    webpackConfig: {
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
            // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules;
            // we're allowing absolute imports to be satisfied from the src/
            // directory.
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'), 
                'node_modules'
            ],
            alias: {
                // Could also be covered by a modules clause, but we are
                // sticking with an alias instead to cover only exactly
                // absolute "styleguidist/..." imports.
                'styleguidist': path.join(__dirname, 'styleguidist'),
            }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'babel-loader',
                            options: {
                                presets: [
                                    "@babel/preset-env",
                                    "@babel/react",
                                ]
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'ts-loader',
                            options: {
                                // Important! Avoids "Error: TypeScript emitted no output for..." errors
                                compilerOptions: {
                                    noEmit: false,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.svg$/,
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'url-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: '[name].[ext]',
                                outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    }
}
```

- covering `styleguidist/` absolute imports could be covered with the `modules:` clause, but in this case I opted for an alias instead. You might judge this differently :)
- I'm setting a rather restrictive regime of documenting only components with examples; get rid of it if you don't want that.
- The difficulties are in configuring webpack with the correct loaders; I've enabled typescript, TSX and JSX, as well as pulling in font resources.
- **Important**: wrapper is in `styleguidist/MuiThemeWrapper.tsx`.

And that's my wrapper `styleguidist/MuiThemeWrapper.tsx`:

(for MUI v5, please see the answer to [MUI v5 + React styleguidist + ScopedCSSBaseline + createTheme styleOverrides: body fontSize change not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69586769))

```
import React from 'react'

import "fontsource-roboto/400.css"
import "fontsource-roboto/500.css"
import "fontsource-roboto/700.css"
import "fontsource-roboto-mono/400.css"

import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline'

const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({})

const MuiThemeWrapper = ({children}) => (
    <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
)

export default MuiThemeWrapper
```

- explicitly pulling in the Roboto fonts I need in my react+Material UI project.
- applying the CSS baseline definition, as otherwise the `font-family`s won't be correctly defined.