# MUI v5 + React styleguidist + ScopedCSSBaseline + createTheme styleOverrides: body fontSize change not working

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, themes

I've migrated two MUI-powered UIs vom MUI v4 to v5, which both have their body fontSize overriden, as explained in the MUI migration guide: this is to keep the v4 design decision to default to Typography body2 font size. This works as expected.

Now I would like to also ensure proper MUI v4 font size default in my Styleguidist component style guide. I've created a `MuiThemeWrapper` and wired up in `styleguide.config.js`:

```json
styleguideComponents: {
    Wrapper: path.join(__dirname, 'styleguidist/MuiThemeWrapper.tsx')
},
```

The wrapper basically does this:

```js
const appTheme = createTheme(
    {
        components: {
            MuiCssBaseline: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    body: {
                        fontSize: '0.875rem', // ...go back to typography body2 font size as in MUI v4.
                        lineHeight: 1.43,
                        letterSpacing: '0.01071em',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        palette: {
            mode: 'light',
            primary: { main: '#009999' },
            secondary: { main: '#ffc400' },
        },
    })

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={appTheme}>
        <ScopedCssBaseline>
            {children}
        </ScopedCssBaseline>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
```

However, this does not set the expected font size to 14px, but instead to 16px. What am I doing wrong, is the body styleOverride in this case even correct?

[image: Edit styleguidist-mui-example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After nosing around even more in [ScopedCssBaseline.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/512896973499adbbda057e7f3685d1b23cc02de9/packages/mui-material/src/ScopedCssBaseline/ScopedCssBaseline.js#L36), it finally occurred to me that there is in fact the `MuiScopedCssBaseline` defined as a valid `components` member when using `createTheme()`. Instead of `body` it's necessary to specify the `styleOverrides` for element `root`.

That is:

```js
const appTheme = createTheme(
    {
        components: {
            MuiScopedCssBaseline: {
                styleOverrides: {
                    root: {
                        fontSize: '0.875rem', // ...go back to typography body2 font size as in MUI v4.
                        lineHeight: 1.43,
                        letterSpacing: '0.01071em',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        palette: {
            mode: 'light',
            primary: { main: '#009999' },
            secondary: { main: '#ffc400' },
        },
    })
```

The updated codesandbox example now works as expected.

This also updates the answer [Setup react-styleguidist, Create React App, Typescript, Material UI and styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64370534) and brings it up-to-date with MUI v5.